# Trying to access android device using adb, but devices is not getting listed in adb Devices

Tags: android, adb

I have a htc device on android 4.1.1. I have installed htc drivers, but the device is not listed as plugged into a usb. The device starts charging when plugged into usb - the cable is fine. What else could be causing this issue?

Comment: Try a different cable. Some charging cables are *only* for charging and lack the pins required to pass data.

Comment: try adb kill-server and then adb start-server

Comment: is connection mode set to MTP (there should be a notification when connected switchable between cam PTP and MTP) ? Enable usb debugging in developer options

Comment: changed the usb cable and that worked thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you are on windows try installing [the android universal USB driver](http://adbdriver.com/)

If you are on MacOS you need [android file transfer](https://www.android.com/filetransfer/)

If this doesn't work try changing USB port and make sure that your device is conected as Mass Storage.